# Using Nihibernate with system dynamic linq for Query<T>

Tags: mysql, nhibernate, dynamic-linq

I am trying to use system.dynamic.linq to create dynamic sorting.

this, is the query that I use:

```
var query = dalSession.Query<T>().AsQueryable();
var res = (from x in query orderby "x.FirstName" select x)
```

this is the mysql output:

```
select
     affiliate0_.id as id0_,
     affiliate0_.first_name as first6_0_,
from affiliate affiliate0_ order by 'x.FirstName' //FirstName as well
```

So you can see that the output went to the mysql query is the direct string, and not its reflection, (`'x.FirstName'`) or (`'FirstName'`).
This has no meaning in mysql context, it looks like I need order by `affiliate0_.first_name`.
Is there anyway to provide the Nhibernate the member itself?  So the compiled query will be done normally?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the " from you requiry. "x.FirstName" is seen as a string and translated to a sql string.

Comment: but this is the problem, I have the FirstName (member name) as a string. I want to do Dynamic sorting.

Comment: You have to make a switch for each member you want to sort on, so you can provide the correct dynamic query.

Comment: You can do this query with the queryover API.

Answer (score 0):

The "x" has no meaning inside the dynamic string.

Remove the `x.` (i.e. leave just "FirstName") and it should work.

Using a method call instead of the query comprehension syntax, you'd get:

```
var res = query.Orderby("FirstName")
```

Comment: Thanks. But if look at my post, you can see that I already tried `FirstName` without `x`.  I just did : `(from x in query select x).OrderBy(x =>"FirstName")` and I get the same result in mysql query. Thanks

Comment: @SexyMF did you see that he has no `x =>` in his code? you always specified to sort by a constant string and no property with this name. copy Diegos code as is

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it as follows (as Diego suggested)?
`(from x in query select x).OrderBy("FirstName")`

Because I think the dynamic linq orderby extension method is not executed when you use `(x => "FirstName")`

Otherwise try this:
`(from x in query select x).OrderBy("it.FirstName")`

BTW I renamed the OrderBy method in Dynamic.cs to DynamicOrderBy because I had some situations where the not dynamic linq OrderBy method was executed too:

`public static IQueryable<T> DynamicOrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string ordering, params object[] values)` and use that one instead:

`(from x in query select x).DynamicOrderBy("FirstName")`

Answer (score 0):

```
var param = Expression.Parameter("x");
var prop = Expression.Property(param, "FirstName");
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<User, string>>(prop, param);
query.Orderby(lambda);
```